# Отправка писем средствами PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php
$to= "morpeh_91@mail.ru" ;
$headers = 'From: 7.stalker@mail.ru'; 
$message="Приветики всем !";
$subject = "Birthday Reminders for August";
mail($to,$subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Никакой реакции в почтовом ящике, скрипт вроде работает, локальный сервер XAMPP.

Comment: А скрипт на хостинге работает или на localhost типа denwer?

Comment: я ж написал локальный сервер XAMPP

Comment: http://makegood.ru/tools/8/#3

Comment: Может как в денвере стоит заглушка не отправку и складывает в папку все?

Answer (score 2):

Вот тут понятно описано решение Вашей проблемы: [PHP mail под Windows, отправка почты из PHP скриптов](http://www.simplecoding.org/php-mail-pod-windows.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
class SendMail {

private $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
private $to, $params, $subject, $mess, $from, $attach;

function __construct() {

}

function setTo($to) {
    $this->to = $to;
}

function setReply($to) {
    $this->headers = $this->headers . 'Reply-To: ' . $to . PHP_EOL;
}

function setSubj($subject) {
    $this->subject = $subject;
}

function setMess($mess) {
    $this->mess = $mess;
}

function setFrom($name='', $mail='') {
    $this->from = 'From: ' . ($name ? $name : $this->params['site_sender']) .
                '<' . ($mail ? $mail : $this->params['site_mail']) . '>' . PHP_EOL;
}

function addAttach($name, $source) {
    $this->attach .=
                '------fiugKbl8-m2WxH5pVxYzJ7dsc:1302108435' . PHP_EOL .
                'Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="' . $name . '"' . PHP_EOL .
                'Content-Disposition: attachment' . PHP_EOL .
                'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL .
                chunk_split(base64_encode($source)) . PHP_EOL;
}

function sendMess($admin_info='0') {
        if (!$this->from) {
            $this->setFrom();
        }
        $headers  = 'Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary="----fiugKbl8-m2WxH5pVxYzJ7dsc:1302108435"' . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= 'Software: http://visionscms.com/' . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= $this->from;
        $headers .= $this->headers;
        $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        if ($admin_info) {
            $adm = "\r\n\n\n\n------\n" .
                    '<b>&#1044;&#1072;&#1090;&#1072;:</b> ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL .
                    '<b>Site:</b> http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . PHP_EOL .
                    '<b>URL:</b> http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . PHP_EOL .
                    '<b>&#1041;&#1088;&#1072;&#1091;&#1079;&#1077;&#1088;:</b> ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . PHP_EOL .
                    '<b>IP:</b> ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $this->mess = $this->mess . nl2br($adm);
        }

        $mess = '------fiugKbl8-m2WxH5pVxYzJ7dsc:1302108435' . PHP_EOL .
                'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . PHP_EOL .
                'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL .
                chunk_split(base64_encode($this->mess)) . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL .
                $this->attach .
                '------fiugKbl8-m2WxH5pVxYzJ7dsc:1302108435--';
        // Mail it
        if(mail($this->to, $this->subject, $mess, $headers)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    function validateMail($mail) {
        return filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Просто и удобно.